# Extract SAS Stored Process web Service in Python and store it in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I have a created a SAS Stored process and was also able to create a web service through SAS Management Console for the same ,

I want to execute that stored process in the web service through Python , and would like to store the data set generated by the stored process in a data frame in Python .

I would really appreciate if I could that the process is possible , and If yes , how should I proceed with it.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible or not.  Pandas can read xport and sas7bdat though  http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#io-sas-reader

Comment: @JohnE +1 good to know that Panda can deal with xport and sas7bdat

Comment: @Jinsi what SAS version are you on?

Comment: @VasilijNevlev  sorry, I should have noted that ability to read sas7bdat is coming in next release (0.18) but ability to read xport files is already available.

Comment: @JohnE, got it, thank you for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about python but it appears that it is possible to receive data in JSON format (see [Python - Parsing JSON Data Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675849/python-parsing-json-data-set))

The [SASjs](https://sasjs.io) framework makes it super easy to build SAS web services on both SAS 9 and Viya, eg:

```
%let appLoc=/Public/app;  /* Configure Metadata or Viya Folder location here */
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/all.sas";
%inc mc; /* compile macros */
filename ft15f001 temp;
parmcards4;
  %webout(OPEN)
  proc sql;
  create table areas as select distinct area from sashelp.springs;
  %webout(OPEN)
  %webout(OBJ,areas)
  %webout(CLOSE)
;;;;
%mp_createwebservice(path=&appLoc/common,name=appinit)
```

Comment: Good soution, but if the user is on 9.3M2 or 9.4, SAS provides PROC JSON that does the job just as well without the need to rely on 3rd party macros.

Comment: Our platform is 9.03.01M2P081512 and proc json is not available.. But that's a good point, answer updated.